# Which is the landing page and which is the homepage?

Tags: website-design, homepage, landing-page

So I'm confused about which page is considered home and which is considered landing.

I got 2 web pages: 1 page is the login page when the user enters the website URL and other is the notification page after the user has been logged in.

My assumption is that the login page is the landing page and the notification page that the user goes to when they click on the website logo button on the top left corner is the home page. Am I correct or is it the other way around?

Comment: Hi @btrballin . Did you get your query answered ? If yes, please mark the correct answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Landing Page**
Generally:
1. Page shown to the user visiting the site for the first time.
2. Page shown to the user when the user is visiting your site via some other source.
3. "Home Page" and "Landing Page" could be considered as one.

**Home Page**
Generally:
1. Page appears after clicking "Home" tab on the site.
2. Page appearing right after "Landing Page".

**Overall**
Terminology depends on the basis of navigation and sitemap.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Probably correct. Although it isn't really relevant for your site.

A landing page is a page user sees when coming to the site from somewhere else. Typically this a special page shown on first visit or when coming from a specific source such as an advertising campaign. The main point here is to show the user the info relevant to the reason you think he is on the site without extra interface clutter. Basically show the user that this is the site he wants and why. And a direct access to what you think he wants to do or what you want him to do. I don't think there is any point using the term for a login page, just think of it as login page, but it is probably accurate enough in this case, since your site is that simple.

A home page is the default page of the site. The place you from a landing page when you "enter the site" or from an error page when you "return to the site" or, yes, from the site logo when you are on the site. A site could have different subsites with their own homepages. Generally it is also the page that is returned when you type just the domain name as address, but it could redirect to a landing page or login page under certain conditions. It is related to the logical structure of the site and since there is no hard limit on how messed up or complex that can be, there might not always be a simple way to spot the homepage.

Comment: +1. This answer correctly points out that landing page and home page perform **different functions**. A landing page may be the same as the home page, or may be different, depending on whether you want to coincide or separate those functions.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter as long as your team all agrees on terminology. But, generally, the 'home' page is where a user would go if they selected the 'home' option from the menu.

Comment: Don't really like this as answer, but kudos for pointing out "It doesn't matter as long as your team all agrees on terminology." Gets forgotten too easy that no authoritative source of one true jargon really exists. As long as people you communicate with understand what you mean, you are doing it right.

Comment: @VilleNiemi what part don't you like about this answer?

Comment: Well, it has **two** sentences, and I gave you kudos for the first one... It is true enough, but not really that useful. Don't mind it. Not like it matters whether I like it or not.

Comment: @VilleNiemi no offense or anything taken! Just like to try and improve my answers when I can. That said, I'm also a fan of short-and-to-the-point. I'm not convinced this question needs a long answer. :)

Comment: Agree with you on that!

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar situation on our learning site. 
I will tell you what we have done here. 
The moment URL is entered, we have a page that asks for login details. And we call it Home page. The default whenever a user visits the site. So its a home page for us and the users.

The page that appears after login, is the "Landing Page".
Its a page after the login process, hence its landing page for us.

This is how we differentiate the home and landing page.

Actually its not a great confusion but how its being developed in the team and as @DA01 mentioned rightly, it depends on the terminology team is comfortable with.